# Applying for phd with flunked course in master

Tags: phd, application

Well, here's the thing. I'm a 2nd year ME master but enrolled in a CSE course and got flunked. So up to now, I enrolled 8 course in my first year (4+4). Without the failed course, I get GPA 3.52 for the rest seven courses. My GPA drops to 3.0, if that course is included. So I plan to take one more course to balance my GPA in this semester. Actually, I feel confident about the courses in this semester. 
Meanwhile, I'm gonna apply for phd in this semester. So how will the failed course affect on my application for phd? Am I supposed to submit transcript with 7 or 8 courses?

Comment: Is it even possible to get a course removed from your transcript (after you've received a grade)? I don't think my university allows such a thing, but I guess that may not be a universal quality.